# How to reorder factors based on degree of absolute differences of dodged variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe of binary categorical variable V0 (A, B), and 22 (V1-V22) continuous variables representing different cell types. My end goal is to have boxplot with dodged boxes based on V0, arranged based on "absolute difference of mean" between A and B within each of the V1-V22 types.

Thank you

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(ggpubr)

## dummy data frame

a <- as.data.frame(sample(c('A', 'B'), 10000, replace=TRUE))
b <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(rnorm(n = 10000, mean = c(0, 5, 20), sd = c(1, 5, 20)))))
c <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(rnorm(n = 10000, mean = c(3, 6, 9), sd = c(1, 4, 5)))))
x <- cbind(a,b,c)
colnames(x) <- c("v0", "v1", "2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9", "v10")

## ## melt data frame
x_melt <- melt(x, id.vars = c("v0"))

## plot
ggplot(x_melt, aes(x= fct_reorder(variable, value, .fun =mean, .desc = T),
                   y=(value)))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=v0), outlier.alpha = 0, coef = 0, alpha = 0.9)+
  labs(x="variable", y="value", fill="Race")+
  stat_compare_means(aes(group = v0), 
                     label = "p.signif", label.y.npc = 0.5, hide.ns=T)
```

So basically, I want the absolute difference between A and B to be the value upon which variables V1:v10 are ordered:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to reordered your boxplots based on the absolute difference between mean of A and B, you can first create a new dataset that will calculate the absolute difference and re-order your variable.

```r
library(tidyverse)
order_x <- x %>% group_by(v0) %>% pivot_longer(., -v0, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  group_by(v0, Variable) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(., names_from = v0, values_from = Mean) %>%
  mutate(Abs_Diff = abs(A-B)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Abs_Diff))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Variable     A     B Abs_Diff
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 v2        8.26  8.73   0.467 
 2 v1        7.99  8.42   0.433 
 3 v5        8.16  7.96   0.204 
 4 v3        8.27  8.44   0.170 
 5 v7        5.97  6.07   0.105 
 6 v6        5.92  6.01   0.0997
 7 v8        5.95  6.02   0.0704
 8 v10       5.95  6.01   0.0558
 9 v9        6.03  6.08   0.0420
10 v4        8.25  8.28   0.0356
```

So, then we can re-order your values for plotting with ggplot, here I used `tidyr` instead of `reshape` in your example, but basically the result should be the same

```r
library(tidyverse)
x_plot <- x %>% group_by(v0) %>% pivot_longer(., -v0, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value")
```

And now, you can plot your boxplot and pass the order of variables from `ordrer_x` into the function `scale_x_discrete`

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x_plot, aes(x = Variable, y = Value, fill = v0))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha = 0, coef = 0, alpha = 0.9)+
  labs(x="variable", y="value", fill="Race") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(order_x$Variable))+
  ylim(-2,15)
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. That is exactly what I was looking for. Turned out that relative difference will produce an even better visualization. Also thanks for pointing out pivot_longer and pivot_wider. Really helpful.

Comment: Glad to be able to help you ;)